# Popover not attached to anchor

Tags: macos, cocoa, popover, xcode-storyboard

I'd like to show a popover with it's arrow to a button that is part of my view (e.g. button is on my main view). I do this in Interface Builder storyboard editor (ctrl drag from button to popup contents view). Popup shows but not attached to the button. What I found for the buttons on the toolbar popover shows attached to the button as expected. Anchor property of the segue is set to this button.  Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001).

Edit: images of what I do:
1) Storyboard. First I ctrl drag from toolbar button to first controller, then ctrl drag to second controller from second button.
[image]
2) Correctly attached popover
[image]
3) Popover not attaches to in-view button.
[image]

Comment: Please attach sample code. Thanks

Comment: @xhruso00 I do this in Interface Builder, no code yet. I add a view controller for popover to storyboard and then connect it using a popover segue with the button on my view, that it.

Comment: If you don't provide sample please attach pictures to your code and show me what is correct behaviour and what's not. It's quicker than posting unaccepted answer. I am spending my time for you (unpaid).

Comment: @MarekH created an empty test project and added images to question. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Added answer. Looks like a bug report has to be filled. I even double checked the source code of storyboard (which is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Following method shows that the sending view is nil and by default contentview of window is used for popover.

So to fix just check if the positioningView is nil. if yes, set it to be button (create outlet for it).

Add following method to your viewController

```
- (void)presentViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController asPopoverRelativeToRect:(NSRect)positioningRect ofView:(NSView *)positioningView preferredEdge:(NSRectEdge)preferredEdge behavior:(NSPopoverBehavior)behavior
{
  //do custom implementation (workaround)
  [super presentViewController:viewController asPopoverRelativeToRect:positioningRect ofView:positioningView preferredEdge:preferredEdge behavior:behavior];
}
```

Comment: One problem I see with this is to how to determine after which button this method is called in first place (I have multiple buttons in a real application).

Comment: check which one is pressed (state). Don't forget to check that one of callers might be toolbaritem. This you have to check with XIBs.